# Method of moment estimates for n Bernoulli trials

Tags: self-study, bernoulli-distribution, method-of-moments

Let $X_1, X_2 \dots X_N$ be the indicators of $n$ Bernoulli trials with probability of success $p$.

What is the method of moments estimate of $p$?

Exhibit method of moments estimates for $p \cdot (1 - p) / n$ using only the first moment and then using only the second moment of the population. How do we show that these estimates conincide?

Argue that in this, the indicators of $n$ Bernoulli trials case all frequency substitution estimates of $q(p)$ must agree with the mean of the indicators of $n$ Bernoulli trials.

Could I use the example , Let X1, X2, ..., Xn be normal random variables with mean μ and variance σ2. What are the method of moments estimators of the mean μ and variance σ2? in this URL  https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/193 ?

Also, Could I use the analysis of the variance of binomial distribution contained in the answers to this Mathematics Stack Exchange URL https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240070/variance-of-binomial-distribution?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: Please make sure to [acknowledge your sources](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and credit all copied text.  Some of the text here appears to be copied nearly word-for-word from Section 2.5, [p.139](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjB47Pa0vnSAhVnjVQKHagiAm0QFgggMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.mit.edu%2F~liewang%2FPages%2520from%2520BickelMathematicalStatistics4.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHrfYPcVUau_c_DWmtTTC3WrxEZcQ&sig2=sSSVi-0NWlNOKdzr0VfvFA&bvm=bv.151325232,d.cGw), Q4 of Peter Bickel and Kjell Doksum's book *Mathematical Statistics*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: "method of moments" means you set sample moments equal to population/theoretical moments.

For example, the first sample moment is $\bar{X} = n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, and the second sample moment is $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$. In general, the $k$th sample moment is $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^k$, for some integer $k$.

The first population moment is $E[X] = \sum_x x P(X=x)$, and the second population moment is $E[X^2] = \sum_x x^2 P(X=x)$. In general the $k$th population moment is $E[X^k] = \sum_x x^k P(X=x)$. Or if your random variable $X$ is a continuous random variable, you would use integrals and density functions: $E[X] = \int x^k f(x) dx$.

In one of your cases, you would solve the following equation for the parameter of interest:
$$
E[X] = \bar{X} \tag{1}.
$$

With normal data, since you have two parameters ($\mu$ and $\sigma^2$), you need to solve two equations:
\begin{align*}
E[X] &= \bar{X}, \\
E[X^2] &= n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X^2_i.
\end{align*}

What equations do I solve for Bernoulli data and one parameter to get the variance in terms of the one parameter?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What equations do I solve for Bernolli data and one parameter to get the variance in terms of the one parameter? Also, what about the all frequency substitution estimates of q(p) which I asked earlier?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the analysis of the variance of binomial distribution contained in the answers to this Mathematics Stack Exchange URL https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240070/variance-of-binomial-distribution, I believe that that the mean, variance and higher moments of the sum of n iid bernoulli variables with parameter p is binomial(p,n).So, the mean of S is n*p and the variance of S is n*p*(1 - p).

Comment: @Taylor, Is my answer correct? Thank you.

Comment: yes that's correct. However the first sample moment, $\bar{X}$, is this sum you call $S$, divided by the sample size $n$. The first moment is what you need to use in your derivations of the parameter estimates. So keep going. Try to plug in stuff for equation (1) of my answer, and see if you get something sensible.